# Правильно ли я возвращаю значение?

Tags: javascript

Имеется переменная типа `string`, в нее приходит данные от функции с возвращаемым значением `Promise<any>`

Вопрос один, правильно ли написан код, для возвращения значения?

```
let token: string = await this.storage.get('token').then((val: string) => val);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нет, неправильно, `await` возвращает значение из `Promise`, а в вашем случае вы его уже разрезолвили вызвав метод `then`.

1 способ получить значение:

```
let token: string = await this.storage.get('token');
```

2 способ:

```
let token: string;
this.storage.get('token').then((val: string) => token = val);
```